# how to debug local php application running on WAMP server exposed publicly via ngrok using visual studio code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, wampserver, ngrok

I am trying to test my dialogflow fulfilment webhook(which needs to be publicly accessible) PHP endpoint. I am using WAMP server and visual studio code as IDE to run my PHP application on my local and made it publicly accessible using ngrok. Using localhost URL, I am able to debug the application using xdebug extension. But when I use the ngrok URL, I am able to access it perfectly but I am not able to debug it. I have tried to follow this link :
https://hajekj.net/2016/09/06/remotely-debugging-php-on-azure-web-apps-with-ngrok/ , but it is using TCP endpoint, whereas I need an https endpoint. How can I debug in this case?

When we use ngrok tunnelling, doesn't it finally route all the requests we receive to localhost? Because I am getting the desired results, but not able to debug.

Comment: what are you debugging if not the request?

Comment: You can debug PHP code with the next functions `ini_set("display_errors", 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I am debugging the requests. When I am using ngrok, I am unable to hit any breakpoints.

Comment: @FernandoUrban, I actually want to hit debug point in ide

Comment: There is no IDE where you can do this at all because PHP is an script language executed on the server side, is not a down level compile language

Comment: You should to debug it by your hand step by step stopping your code, this is the best practice, or see if Dreamviewer provide something similar

Comment: @FernandoUrban There are in fact any number of IDE's that with the help of XDEBUG will allow you to debug PHP code.

Comment: @FernandoUrban, I am actually able to debug using IDE using localhost, but the issue is with when trying to debug using public URL(from ngrok)

Comment: @RiggsFolly The guy is asking about to debug public url which is in php with an IDE, i apologize about this but where the heck you can get something about that?

Comment: @FernandoUrban https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=debug+php+ide Some free and others behind a pay barrier

Comment: @FernandoUrban you can see this link https://hajekj.net/2016/09/06/remotely-debugging-php-on-azure-web-apps-with-ngrok/  it is possible, I think I am missing something. But not able to figure it out exactly.

Comment: obviously you need more kind of acess because for privacy and security reasons you're not allow to debug remote/public url in php